# An empty extra line in multlined inside cases

Tags: spacing, cases, mathtools

If I put a `multlined` inside a `cases` environment, there appears an empty extra line.

```
\[
\begin{cases}
first row & aaa \\
second row & bbb \\
\begin{multlined}[b][10em]
third row part 1 \\
third row part 2 \\
third row part 3
\end{multlined}
& ccc \\
fourth row & ddd
\end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

The effect is stable, and does not appear in `aligned` or other similar environments I checked, only in `cases`. Is there any non-hacker way to overcome this issue?

Comment: as work arround try `\[
\begin{cases}
first row   & aaa \\
second row  & bbb \\
\begin{multlined}[b]
third row part 1 \\[-1em]
third row part 2 \\
third row part 3
\end{multlined}
            & ccc \\
fourth row  & ddd
\end{cases}
\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dcases` environment, since you load `mathtools` for  `multlined`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{dcases}
first row & aaa \\
second row & bbb \\
\begin{multlined}[b][10em]
third row part 1 \\
third row part 2 \\
third row part 3
\end{multlined}
& ccc \\
fourth row & ddd
\end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use `dcases` (comes with `mathtools`) instead of `cases`. Also, `amsmath` has a some bugs that can be fixed just by loading `mathtools` package.